# HDFS + Taking long time to copy files from hdfs to local folder

Tags: networking, redhat, hadoop, hdfs

we have Hadoop cluster that used HDFS filesystem

the problem is about copying file from HDFS to local folder that take huge time

for example usually copy file  with size of **3G** takes few second , but on our cluster machines its take around 30 min

here is example:

```
su hdfs
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /data/file_hdfs.zip /var/tmp
```

on other session we get the following after **15min**

```
du -sh  /var/tmp/*
1.1G    /var/tmp/file_hdfs.zip.zip._COPYING_
```

we already verified the following

1. CPU load Everage on all data node machine is ok
2. CPU Util on all machine is ok
3. MTU settings seems to be ok ( MTU set 1500 on all nodes )
4. HDFS is healthy, we checked that by `hdfs fsck /`
5. memory is fine ( from `free -g` )

we checked the NIC also as

```
ethtool p1p1
Settings for p1p1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

what else we need to verify in order to find why copying files from HDFS to local folder take huge time

we also verified the name-node machines. with `iperf3`  tool ( name-node machines are VM machine )

```
iperf3 -i 1 -t 60 -c namenode01
Connecting to host namenode01, port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
.
.

[  4]  56.00-57.00  sec   108 MBytes   903 Mbits/sec    2    327 KBytes
[  4]  57.00-58.00  sec   103 MBytes   865 Mbits/sec    7    197 KBytes
[  4]  58.00-59.00  sec   103 MBytes   868 Mbits/sec    4    279 KBytes
[  4]  59.00-60.00  sec   104 MBytes   871 Mbits/sec   14    335 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-60.00  sec  5.99 GBytes   858 Mbits/sec  828             sender
[  4]   0.00-60.00  sec  5.99 GBytes   857 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

on namenode03

```
 iperf3 -i 10 -s

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-60.04  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-60.04  sec  5.99 GBytes   857 Mbits/sec                  receiver
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
```

---